# Which LEGO vehicle set do I have here? 6 wheels and orange bricks

Tags: piece-information

Can anyone help identify this kit? I received it in a bag with the number 5 on the outside and the year 2011. I'm really keen to build it but need some help identifying it so that I can get the instructions.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Set [4635 - Fun with Vehicles](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4635-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). Specifically the tow truck pictured top center.

[image]